# Why radial radiation profiles of axisymmetric electric arc cross section is Gaussian?

Tags: radiation, plasma-physics

I've recently found from experiment data that, the radial intensity profiles of an axisymmetric electric arc cross section is pretty close to Gaussian Distribution (R-square>0.99). [fitting image](https://ibb.co/xqv4TLg)
The original thought came from literature "Preliminary plume characteristics of an arcjet thruster. February 1990. DOI: 10.2514/6.1990-2645", but no reference or derivation was provided to support the validity of this fitting curve.
[screenshot of reference](https://ibb.co/kMhzK5Z)
It makes me wonder the relations between arc plasma radiation and Gaussian distribution. There must be some fundamental truth in arc plasma radiation process to account for such a close fitting.(Note that the fitting data used above is raw.) However, I haven't found explanations concerning this discovery on internet. Hope I can find it in this community, thanks in advance!

Comment: Gaussian as a function of what?  The energy?  The velocity?  The spatial position relative to the arc location?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. The " fitting image" above is a data set of line-of-sight integration of a certain spectral line through one arc column slice with respect to lateral position. However, X-axis is just a 1-to-n vector rather than centered -n-to-+n vector. Schematic drawing as such [link1](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0924013612002889-gr6.jpg) [link2](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ze-Guo/publication/338509713/figure/fig3/AS:845795217666051@1578664702765/Schematic-diagram-of-Abel-inverse-transformation_W640.jpg) @honeste_vivere